# What is the relationship between 3xx and caching around cloudfront?

Tags: redirect, caching, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache

I came across this issue and tried to get my head around caching and redirection. Base on what I read **301** and **302** [http protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections), this is how I see it, `a request sends to server (in this case cloudfront) and triggers a direction` (base on the configuration but we assume this is default settings). In the `response`, the client sees a **301** or **302**, which `indicates the resources they get back`. If the status is 301, means that the `link has permanently moved`, `therefore new resources will return` back to the client. While **302** tells the client that the `resource is found and here it is, without doing any further action`.

["If your origin returns a 301 or 307 status code, CloudFront doesn't follow the redirect to the new location."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-3xx-status-codes.html)

From the above quote, does this mean 301/307 will return cached resource from the backend? Does Cloudfront uses a the status code for the redirection different?

I know I have too many questions within one post, but my main concern is caching and redirection. Can someone explain this relationship in a layman term? Thank you in advance

By the way, this is how I trigger my redirection:

Navigate to **https://example.com/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://example.com/copy/index.html">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/copy/index.html">
</head>
```

**Extra notes:**

- [Cache control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)

Explains what we should do to manage our cache on the Cloudfront

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"If your origin returns a 301 or 307 status code, CloudFront doesn't follow the redirect to the new location."

Above line means that CloudFront forwards the response to the client instead of following the redirection provided by Origin.

What It does:
Client --> CloudFront --> Origin (301) <--> CloudFornt --> Client (gets new location)

As you can see CloudFront forwards the response header (along with status code) to client and it's the client who needs to follow the redirection.

CloudFront doesn't do:
Client --> CloudFront --> Origin(301) --> CloudFront (follows 301 and makes a request to new location)-->origin

Though CloudFront caches the 3xx response which means the next time if someone makes the same request, CloudFront serves response from it's cache.

When CloudFront server 301/307 by his own(not from Origin):
HTTP to HTTPS redirection (301 for GET, 307 for POST) or Lambda@edge configured to do so.

Comment: does the status code is 301 or 302 make any different to the cached data that is returned from the CloudFront? If I made an update to the website and wished to have data to be validate and recached if new data is provided.

Comment: 301 and 302 doesn't response doesn't contain any data, so CloudFront is caching just the response header nothing else, if you change in your content, CloudFront serves 301/302 from the cache , it doesn't matter because the  new location where client will connect, you need to take care of the new location, CloudFront caches so if the data has changed, you need to perform in validation otherwise you can choose TTL/Cache-Control configuration to don't allow CloudFront to cache on specific page.

Comment: Thank James, I think I understand what you mean now. Appreciate for your help. Just checked out the Cloudfront cache control, and I realise I placed my focus on the wrong issue, so it snowballed from there.

Comment: How do you prevent CloudFront from caching the redirect. When I go from mywebpage.com/subpage?id=123 and then mywebpage.com/subpage?id=456, cloudfront returns a 301 with mywebpge.com/subpage?id=123.